# How to get windows logged in user id from ASP.NET with anonymous access

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application which is set on forms and anonymous access. I have a default page on which I want to get the current windows logged in user, it's an ASP.Net application.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can't. Anonymous access means anyone can visit the page without telling the server his identity. WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent will just tell you the server account the web app is running under for anonymous access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you can try with this code

```
   WindowsIdentity wi = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
   var result = wi.Name;
   var anonymous = wi.IsAnonymous; //For ensure your authentification mode
```

You can use this code

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

But you must ensure that yo have added your principal in your thread in your security package, maybe httpmodule. (If you have custom authentification and Authorization)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the [HttpContext.User.Identity.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
        var w = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

        this.HttpContext.Trace.Warn(w);
```